# How to disable Data Frame Appending on existing values in pandas "df.to_csv"

Tags: python, pandas

I was successful in creating a table of values from different csv files located in one folder. I combined these files into one table as shown in the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGDwG.png)

However when i run the code again, it appends the values instead of overwriting them. How can i disable that appending?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QfgD.png)

```
import pandas as pd 

from glob import glob

stock_files= sorted(glob('counter/*.csv'))


df= pd.concat((pd.read_csv(file).assign(filename=file) for file in 
stock_files), ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv('counter/data.csv')
df.sort_values('Counter')
```

Comment: Include code as formatted code, not as image.

Comment: @zabop I am sorry, done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's an implicit loop in your code as a result of your call `.to_csv()` and your call to `glob()`

You are saving the output of your concatenation to a .csv file in the same location that you are reading the previous .csv files. This means that every time you run the program you'll add a copy of all of the data into your DataFrame.

You can solve this by:

- saving the file to something other than a .csv
- saving the file to a .csv but in a different location
- modifying your call to glob to exclude counter/data.csv